# Unable to understand functional shorthands

Tags: c++, iterator

I am new to C++. I am reading the C++ Programming Language by Bjarne Stroustrup.

My question is:

1. What is operator++ and operator* in the following code fragment?
2. Are they simply function names?
3. Another question is why is there no `datatype` associated with `lst` in the following statement:

   ```
   Node* end(lst)


   struct Node { Node* next; int data; };
   Node* operator++(Node* p) { return p−>next; }
   int operator*(Node* p) { return p−>data; }
   Node* end(lst) { return nullptr; }
   void test(Node* lst)
   {
   int s = sum<int*>(lst,end(lst));
   }
   ```

Comment: 1) Yes. Look up operator overloading. 2) `Node* end(lst)` appears to be a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `operator++` and `operator*` are overloaded operators which is simply put special functions. They come in handy when you are implementing a custom data type and decide to support increment(`++`) and dereference(`*`) operations. [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) should be a good place to look for before posting such trivial questions.
- The second part of the question - what you posted would produce a compiler error and the actual signature should be `Node* end(Node* lst)`. I'm not sure where you got that from, maybe the author didn't care about the type of `lst` (assumed to be inferred from context) since end of list marker is indicated by `null`(convention).